# Project screencast of a Mac on remote controlled second computer

Tags: mac, display, screen-sharing, remote-control, projector

I have 2 Macs (which I'll call A and B) and a video-projector. Mac B is connected to the video-projector. I want to show on the video-projector the screen of Mac A but the video-projector is too far to be connected to Mac A. So I was looking for a way to connect Mac A to Mac B (via Wifi or such, no cables) which gives the information to the video-projector. I want anyway that the files to show and all the commands are given to Mac A because nobody will have the access to Mac B.

So the question is the following, if I use Mac B as a screen for Mac A, is Mac B going to give the information to video-projector?

Are there better ways for doing this? Does it work also with the sound?

I hope the question is clear, thanks a lot.

P.s. If anybody has a good solution that works on Windows or Linux I would be happy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to have content on the Mac projecting the image, you can use remote access via VNC or ARD. This approach has Mac A acting as a gateway to view and control Mac B.

### Virtual Network Computing / VNC

You can use VNC to remotely connect to and control another computer. [VNC is free and built into OS X](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/).

VNC has the benefit that you can use two different types of computers. VNC is not specific to OS X. You could have a Linux computer could control a Mac, or a Mac control a Windows computer.

### Apple Remote Desktop / ARD

Apple sell a product that builds upon VNC called [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/). ARD allows you to more fully manage and control a Mac computer across a wired or wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vnc connection from the Mac B to Mac A

write in the Safari.app vnc://Mac A and enable screen sharing in the System preferences

Let me know if you need other information

or the other solution can be  TeamViewer